# How to access the tabBarController from FirstViewController?

Tags: iphone

Created a new project from the `Tab Bar Application` template, how can I access `tabBarController` (which is declared in `AppDelegate`) from `FirstViewController`? I'd like to read some attributes in the `tabBarController` from the view controller. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always access the app delegate as follows:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
```

So you should be able to get at the tabBarController by doing this:

```
MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
```

Now refer to delegate.tabBarController.

[In the above, MyAppDelegate is whatever name you gave the class of your app delegate.]